# What do I do when an edit/comment substantively changes a question I answered?

Tags: discussion

For example, in this question, the user [asked how to convert a Python dictionary to and from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199069/python-how-to-use-a-string-to-fill-a-dictionary-in-one-go/24199127#24199127), and I responded with a recommendation that he use `repr` and `eval`. I said that this was a really bad idea, but since he cryptically rejected using `dict.copy()` in the question because "it beats the purpose," I couldn't think of anything else. Shortly after, he commented and said that what he really wanted was to read a dictionary to and from a file.

Someone else gave him the good advice to use the `json` module, and I got a downvote, obviously, from someone who read the edited question and concluded that my answer didn't do anything to actually help him.

In some cases, a question-asker comes back and revises the question in such a way that your original answer is useless, or even misguided. If you don't know how to answer the revised question, or if someone else has already given the correct answer, what should I do? Do I delete my answer that's now irrelevant based on what was said in the comments? Or do I leave it there in case it helps someone who stumbles on the question wanting an answer to what was originally asked?

Comment: Since you were, obviously , trying to help the lad by giving an honest and professional answer, don't lose even a minute to try to keep up with the question's changes. As for the downvoter apparently you found someone that knows how to press only the "down" but not the "edited" button of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that [specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24199127/109702) I would spend a few minutes and expand on it, explain why you said *"There is no reason this is ever a good idea."* and why `dict.copy()` is a better option.

Try not to leave important information in the comments, and don't ask for up voting or answer marking in the comments.

If you make it into a better answer it has a better chance to be useful to someone in the future. You've already received an up vote, or the down voter reversed their vote.